# Is there any way to fill a drawing in C# GDI+, where the drawing involves multile Arcs,Lines?

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, gdi+, gdi

My application involves drawing of custom shapes, in which the details of the shapes are retrieved from the database. Shapes will be Lines, Arcs.

I will calling DrawArc and DrawLine function to draw the custom shapes.

My Problem is I need to fill this custom shape with a background color.

I am using the following namespaces.

```
 using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
 using System.Drawing;
```

**Things that I tried out:**

Graphics.FillRegion Method

```
    private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        // Create a graphics path
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        // Add two lines, a rectangle and an ellipse
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        path.StartFigure();

        path.AddLine(20, 400, 20, 20); // left
        path.AddLine(20, 20, 400, 20); //top
        path.AddLine(400, 20, 400, 400); // right
        path.AddLine(400, 400, 20, 400); // bottom
        path.CloseFigure();

        g.DrawPath(redPen, path);

        Region reg = new Region(path);
        g.FillRegion(Brushes.Green, reg);

        reg.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Using this method it is easy to fill a simple shape, where the start and end points are clearly defined.

But my application involves complex shapes, which is difficult to track the points. If I use this method, filling of background color is not proper.

Pls suggest me some way of filling custom shapes.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered using `FillPath` rather than `FillRegion`?

Comment: Hi Damien, yes I tried FillPath also.. It didn't work out..

Comment: Well, could you at least try to add an example of a shape that your current method *doesn't* get right? It's a little difficult to know what "is not proper" means without having an example to examine.

Comment: Hi Damien, The below link was answered by you    .            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670297/is-there-any-way-to-fill-a-drawing-in-c-sharp-gdi-where-the-drawing-involves-m   T        The problem is for a line diagram, the co-ordinates which is retrived from the Database will not be in the proper order, I mean the start and end points.  So for an instance, if the diagram contains two arcs and lines, since the ordering is not proper, it is easy to draw a diagram but difficult to fill it, Since the tracking the path is difficult.

Comment: I know I previously answered a question of yours where you were specifying lines in the wrong order. Do you not see that when it comes to *filling* a shape, it's even more important that you *do* get the line segments in the correct order, in order for any computer to be able to decide on the difference between "inside" and "outside"?

Comment: Hi damine, Yes it is important. but our internal database can not be changed for this order. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Then your question is actually nothing to do with drawing/filling - it's that you have a set of line/arc segments and you need some algorithm that will sort them (and possibly reverse some of them) such that it produces a "consistent" shape that you can then *use* for drawing/filling. Exactly what the rules are for "consistent" you'd have to carefully define (unless all shapes are simple convex shapes). And once you realise that that's your fundamental problem and you need an algorithm, it doesn't feel like a fit for SO any longer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i was trying out that in between.. also just checking here to find any other way...